# Alignment of input text fields in angular html

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

[image]    [image]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="lable label-default"> Google Location</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='latitude' placeholder="latitude"
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.latitude">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='longitude' placeholder="longitude"
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.longitude">
</div>

 My Css code:

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: left;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
    }
```

I have my Following Output. But I want to align these input text fields one by one with same proper alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done only for geo-location. But if like to get the idea of bootstrap, you can refer [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp) or [Bootstrap offcial web](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/)

The working fiddle [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Varman/cp1frtms/7/)

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label label-default"> Google Location</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name='latitude' placeholder="latitude"
               [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.latitude">
               <input class="form-control" type="text" name='longitude' placeholder="longitude"
               [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.longitude">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

**Update 1** As you updated the requirement, I've updated the fiddle too. So you can easily remove `<div class="row">` and get your expectation

Comment: I just want to align the input text fields (above image shows)one by one with proper alignment..It doesn't matter about the label fields.

Comment: yeah.. \It works well... But there is no gap between two input fields (latitude and longitude).I need some gap between them.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle using `input-gap` class. But we will appreciate if you try and get your job done, because this community is to encourage coders.

Answer (score 1):

Share your css to properly understand the style, but I am assuming the typo `lable` instead of `label` may affect the css rules

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label label-default"> Google Location</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='latitude' placeholder="latitude"
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.latitude">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name='longitude' placeholder="longitude"
                        [(ngModel)]="tourDetails.longitude">
</div>
```

Comment: label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: left;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    text-align: left;
  }

Comment: create a stackblitz or a codesandbox with the code, cannot debug css without a runtime and working example!

Comment: I cannot debug unless I know at which viewport width is this issue happening and the default styles loaded into `.form-group` that may be cascading your styles